# NULLReference Exception C# ASP.Net (Variable Populated yet i get the exception)

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

oQual is a class variable which is assigned to one of the parameters as show in the code below, the problem is if watch this variable at runtime it is already populated with the correct values yet i am getting the NULLReference Exception on the commented line.

```
    Programme oPrograme;
    private Qualification oQual;

    public ProgrammeList(Qualification oQualification)
    {
        oPrograme = new Programme();
        oQual = new Qualification();
        oQual = oQualification;

        this.tQID.Text = oQual.getQualficationID().ToString(); //oQual is already populated yet i am getting null reference expection on this line
        this.tProgName.Text = oQual.getQualificationName();
        this.tProg_Saqa_reg_no.Text = oQual.getQualificationNqfLevel();
        this.tProg_nqf_level.Text = oQual.getQualificationSaqaNo();

    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4SZe.jpg)

Comment: what getQualificationID() is doing? oQual might not be null but the method might return null, or tQID might be null. Show us mire details.

Comment: If you are sure the passed parameter is not null then 100% percent getQualficationID is returning null.

Comment: I have traced the code for getQualficationID() it is returning the correct value.